# Angular 7: NullInjectorError for failing test, service still works in component

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I am  have a failing Karma test due to a NullInjector error for a service.

- The service IS working in the component (problem with test and not with component?),
- the service injection works for other components, and their tests pass

Solutions to similar questions relate to declaring a provider. In my case I have declared a provider (see below), and the service works inside the component.

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[LoginComponent -> AuthenticationProvider]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AuthenticationProvider!
```

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationProvider {
  uri: string
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
     private config: SancusConfiguration,
    ) 
    {

  }
```

The failing test:

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ AppModule ],
      declarations: [  ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I have listed the AuthenticationProvider in providers in the NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ....
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CollapseModule.forRoot(),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [
  AuthenticationProvider,
   .....
  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: you need to add it to the providers in the TestBed, ```TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ AppModule ],
      providers: [AuthenticationProvider],
      declarations: [  ]
    })```. But if you are testing the component, then generally is a good practice to mock the service since it is not important to your test in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have to list your providers in your testing module since `AppModule` does not export its providers.
- You should also not load your entire `AppModule` to test just `LoginComponent`.
- You will have to mock these providers since it looks like they are making network calls.

Code example:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [{provide: AuthenticationProvider,  useValue: mockProvider}, ... ],
  declarations: []
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The tests need to be completely independant from your modules.

So you shouldn't have `imports: [ AppModule ]` in your test.

You should import each components and services used in your component (or mocks of them) and not more. Because if you add more element, your test will not validate the real state of the component.

example:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    MockAnotherComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthenticationProvider,
    {
      provide: Router,
      useValue: mockRouter
    }
  ]
})

... 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-another-component',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class MockAnotherComponent{
  @Input()
  title: string = null;
}
```